php controller not giving info
I have a problem where I need a product list that is stored in a database to be displayed on my start.blade.php page, but an error shows:

Undefined variable $products

Here is all of my code:
start.blade.php:
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <section class="product-section">
        <div class="product-list">
            <h1>Product List</h1>
            @forelse ($products as $product)
                <div class="product">
                    <p>{{ $product->name }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $product->weight }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $product->type }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $product->price }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $product->supplier }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $product->extra }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $product->amount }}</p>
                </div>
            @empty
                <p>No products found.</p>
            @endforelse
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection

web.php:
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
Route::get('/start', [ProductController::class, 'index'])->name('logged.start');

ProductController.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        // Pass the products to the 'logged.start' view
        return view('logged.start', compact('products'));
    }
}

Product.php:
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'weight', 'type', 'price', 'supplier', 'extra', 'amount'];
}

Can someone please help see the fix that neither I nor the robot can't find?
I have tried everything from checking if the routes are correct, to making a new controller, but nothing is making that list appear from the database!

In the controller, before the return, if you add: dd($products); is it fetching data? If so, I've never been a fan of compact myself, so then try with: return view('logged.start', ['products' => $products]); instead.

In your controller, you’re returning the view as logged.start, but your start.blade.php file is likely in the resources/views folder.
return view('start', compact('products'));


The start.blade.php file is located in resources/views/logged folder

What error are you getting?

please replace your return view,
return view('logged.start')->with(['products' => $products]);

I have figured it out! As it turns out i had this in my web.php file:
Route::get('/starter', function () {
    return view('logged.start');
})->name('start');

After deleting it everything started working as it should.
